# How do I construct a matrix using table command. I can not form it's function

Tags: matrix, function-construction, linear-algebra

I have to form a matrix like this. How ever I can not directly input. I have to form a function and then use the table command. I am stuck.
{{2,5,10},{9,12,17},{28,31,36}}

Comment: Your function will take two arguments, the row and column.  Note that each row in the matrix equals some other row plus a constant.  Each column equals another column plus some constant.  If you get stuck with the actual code, add what code you have to your question so we can help you with it.

Comment: What exactly is your function supposed to do? I.e., what are the inputs and what are the outputs? Is it supposed to produce just that one particular 3-by-3 matrix? (If so, what on earth is the point of defining a function to do it, since you already have code to create it?) If you insist on *using* some function explicitly (other than `List`), then how about this: `Map[Plus[{2, 5, 10}, #] &, {0, 7, 26}]`.

Comment: Or use: `Map[Plus[{2, 5, 10}, #] &, Accumulate[{0, 7, 19}]]`. But again, seems pointless to do so when you already have in hand the specific matrix you want.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is an example of finding rules that match number sequences. For problems like these, the answer is less important than understanding the steps you use to find a solution.

A number sequence is a list of numbers that's defined by a rule. If you work out the rule, you can find the numbers in the sequence. Find the rule by looking for a pattern or common factor that defines the next number in the sequence. Finding rules is a combination of logic and intuition.

A simple example is the number sequence (5,9,13,17). The difference between each number is 4, so the rule is to add 4 each time. Mathematica can help find these rules. For example:

```
FindFormula[{5, 9, 13, 17}, n]
(* 1. + 4. n *)
```

For your table, you might begin by looking at each row to find a rule that defines the number sequence. Again, logic and intuition is important, but Mathematica can help. Inspect the first row, and notice that the numbers depend on the column number. For the first row, we can try:

```
FindFormula[{2, 5, 10}, c]
```

and we find $1 + c^2$. For the second and third rows, we use `FindFormula[{9, 12, 17}, c]` and `FindFormula[{28, 31, 36}, c]`. The results are $8 + c^2$ and $27 + c^2$.

Notice the common factor $c^2$, and that each row begins number: 1, 8 and 27. Let's try to find a rule for the sequence (1, 8, 27).

```
FindFormula[{1, 8, 27}, r]
```

We see that $r^3$ is the rule that defines the number sequence for each row. Combining these results for the columns and rows, we can build a table.

```
Table[r^3 + c^2, {r, 3}, {c, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 5 & 10 \\
 9 & 12 & 17 \\
 28 & 31 & 36 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Let me first explain that it makes sense to use `Table` only when you know the functional form of a sequence. In you example one can only guess what was the actual idea for this homework. One possible solution would be

```
Table[j + i^2 - 1, {j, {2, 9, 28}}, {i, 3}]
```

But I would like to emphasize that both, for this forum and for your teacher, you need to demonstrate some work. It is pathetic, but this is the only way to learn something.